# I’d like to grab a few Table TDs from an external website. I want to grab the TD’s only that have certain value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I’d like to grab a few Table TDs from an external website. 
I want to grab the TD’s only that have certain value 
Example table:

```
<table>
<tr><td>green</td><td>0</td><td>5</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Blue</td><td>0</td><td>5</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Red</td><td>0</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td>Yellow</td><td>0</td><td>4</td><td>9</td></tr>
<tr><td>purple</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>white</td><td>0</td><td>6</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>orange</td><td>0</td><td>5</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>grey</td><td>0</td><td>5</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>black</td><td>0</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td>pink</td><td>0</td><td>4</td><td>9</td></tr>
<tr><td>dark green</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>yellow white</td><td>0</td><td>6</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>light green</td><td>0</td><td>5</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>dark Blue</td><td>0</td><td>5</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>dark white</td><td>0</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>
<tr><td>black and yellow</td><td>0</td><td>4</td><td>9</td></tr>
<tr><td>white and green</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>blue and red</td><td>0</td><td>6</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now let’s say I only want to grab Red, Purple, light green, and black and yellow and the first numbered TD for those colors only.

The first number can either be 0 or 1.

As long as the timer is 0 I want it to count the ‘days’, but as soon as one of them had 1 I want it to reset it’s counter.

Let’s say Purple hasn’t been 1 for 26 days I want a counter for 26 days that will reset after it becomes 1 again.

There is only problem though. If a color hasn’t been seen for 7 days it disappears from the table, but I want it to stay on my website until it hits 1 again and shown on the table again…

What I’ve tried:
I tried to grab the whole Table from the external website and ‘hide’ the TD’s I don’t want, but the problem is they disappear from the table as soon as it’s 7 days or higher. 
So they won’t be shown on my website either…

Where do I even start for this? 
Who can help me out where to start..?

Comment: Please post your JS code as well. You state that you have tried something thus far, so we'll need to see it. See MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 1) Grab the page you need with ajax. 2) Either parse the table out of the html using a regex or put the html inside a document so you can select the table. 3) Once you have the table, make it into a html node if it isn't already. 4) The select all the <tr> elements from the table. 5) Loop over the tr elements and check if they contain a td with the color you need. 6) If the tr row has a td cell with the correct color, grab the first td cell with a number in it. 7) Save your results to a database so you can look back into the apst longer than 7 days.